# how to display categories (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

form my table i want to display ratio by categories.
i wrote a code which shows me ratio for everything and i'm stuck 
with splitting it by different categories_id

this is my code

```
SELECT (b.t1/a.t2) as r
FROM 
(
    SELECT avg(items*value) AS T1
    FROM table1
    WHERE YEAR(data) = 2001
) a,
(
    SELECT avg(items*value) AS T2
    FROM table1
    WHERE YEAR(data) = 2002
) b
```

EDIT
i use ms sql server

```
╔═════════════╤════════════╤═══════╤═══════╗
║ category_id │ data       │ items │ value ║
╠═════════════╪════════════╪═══════╪═══════╣
║ 1           │ 2001-02-02 │ 1     │ 5.5   ║
╟─────────────┼────────────┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1           │ 2001-02-03 │ 2     │ 6.1   ║
╟─────────────┼────────────┼───────┼───────╢
║ 1           │ 2001-02-01 │ 3     │ 4.3   ║
╟─────────────┼────────────┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2           │ 2001-02-01 │ 2     │ 2.2   ║
╟─────────────┼────────────┼───────┼───────╢
║ 2           │ 2001-02-02 │ 5     │ 2.3   ║
╚═════════════╧════════════╧═══════╧═══════╝
```

End want to recieve where t1 is avg(items*value) in 2001 and t2 is avg(items*value) in 2002

```
╔═════════════╤═══════════════╗
║ category_id │ ratio (t1/t2) ║
╠═════════════╪═══════════════╣
║ 1           │ 12.2          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────╢
║ 2           │ 10.1          ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────╢
║ 3           │ 111.1         ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────╢
║ 4           │ 222.8         ║
╟─────────────┼───────────────╢
║ 5           │ 333.9         ║
╚═════════════╧═══════════════╝
```

Comment: ok, thank you i will follow your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT T.category_id, (T1.av/T2.av) AS ratio
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT category_id FROM table1
) T
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  category_id, avg(items*value) AS av
    FROM table1
    WHERE YEAR(data) = 2001
    GROUP BY category_id
) T1 ON T.category_id=T1.category_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  category_id, avg(items*value) AS av
    FROM table1
    WHERE YEAR(data) = 2002
    GROUP BY category_id
) T2 ON T.category_id=T2.category_id
ORDER BY T.category_id
```

I assumed that all categories have not necessary values in 2001 and 2002.

If you know that all categories are present in all the years, you can shorten it :

```
SELECT T1.category_id, (T1.av/T2.av) AS ratio
FROM
(
    SELECT  category_id, avg(items*value) AS av
    FROM table1
    WHERE YEAR(data) = 2001
    GROUP BY category_id
) T1 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT  category_id, avg(items*value) AS av
    FROM table1
    WHERE YEAR(data) = 2002
    GROUP BY category_id
) T2 ON T1.category_id=T2.category_id
ORDER BY T1.category_id
```

Comment: i have already done it by myself but thanks, my solution looks almost the same

Answer (score 0):

In your "a table" (year 2001) and "b table" (year 2002), it returns you one row and one column: the average of everything.

My guess is in those sub-queries, you need to get the average of what you what you are looking for and then you would get the ratio you want. You need to group by categories_id and get the average of each categories_id per year.